# Čech cohomology of a contractible space with integer coefficients

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

I am unable to see why the following statement is trivial:

> Since $\mathbb{C}^n$ is contractible, we see that $\check{H}^k(\mathbb{C}^n,\mathbb{Z}) = 0$ for $k>0$.

**Source**: p. 46, "Principles of algebraic geometry" - Griffiths and Harris.

A [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3128666) was asked here earlier also, but it doesn't contain a satisfactory answer.

Comment: the answer there is correct: Cech cohomology is an invariant of homotopy type, so since being contractible means you have the homotopy type of a point, you should attempt to convince yourself of the statement for a point.

Comment: @RyleeLyman Ok. Do we need to use the fact that the Cech cohomology of the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to the simplicial cohomology? Or there is some other reason for Cech cohomology being an invariant of homotopy type? Since Griffiths-Harris doesn't contain much information about Cech cohomology calculations, I will be grateful if you could provide some reference for directly calculating Cech cohomology.

Comment: If you want to use that its the singular cohomology sure, otherwise this can be computed from the definition (use the open cover consisting of the unique point). If you prefer to use singular cohomology, then just compute the singular cohomology of a point.

Comment: @rationalbeing One of the main reasons to call a functor "cohomology" is because it is homotopy invariant (see also: Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms). So whatever source you read they should at least mention that. For a proof you can look here: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~pierre.schapira/lectnotes/AlTo.pdf Section 6.3. Also note that Čech cohomology is isomorphic to singular cohomology **only** for "good" spaces, e.g. cw complexes. So that is not a correct way to look at it.

Comment: @DKS To directly compute the Cech cohomology, will I have to use Leray's theorem which involves finding an acyclic covering so as to avoid the direct limit which comes in the definition of Cech cohomology? I have never seen a direct computation of Cech cohomology, so it will be helpful if you could provide an example.

Comment: @rationalbeing If you calculate Čech cohomology of a point you avoid direct limit because the system is trivial. There is only **one** covering with only **one** open subset. You can't get it simplier. I understand that this is not a typical exercise but do try it.

Comment: @freakish Thanks for the useful comment and sharing a reference. Griffiths-Harris gives just a brief outline of Cech cohomlogy in less than 10 pages. Please let me know a good reference where I can learn the technique for directly calculating Cech cohomology without looking at its equivalence with other cohomologies. I will certainly try to spend more time and do this simple example.

Comment: Bott and Tu, *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology* contains (in my opinion) the best introduction to Cech cohomology for a sheaf. Look there if you feel very confused about all of this.