# Is Čech cohomology homotopy invariant?

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I haven't been able to find a reference for a proof to this result if one exists so I'd love to be pointed in the direction of one.

The answer to this following question relies on this result for example:
[Čech cohomology of a contractible space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3128666/%C4%8Cech-cohomology-of-a-contractible-space)

EDIT:
I am referring to this definition of Čech cohomology:
For a closed topological subspace $A \subset X$ the Čech cohomology is the direct limit of the cohomology of open sets in $X$ containing $A$ - i.e. $\check{H}^n(A) := \varinjlim_{U \in \mathcal{U}_A} H^n(U)$.
or similarly for a closed topological pair:
$\check{H}^n(A,B) := \varinjlim_{(U,V) \in \mathcal{U}_{A,B}} H^n(U,V)$

Comment: The answer is yes for CW complexes since it is isomorphic to singular cohomology.

Comment: Does this depend on the sheaf we choose? if it's $\Bbb{Z}$ then under some certain condition it's singular cohomology. However, if we choose holomorphic sheaf, it may depend on the complex structure of the space, maybe there is something can not be distinguished by homotopy? I am not sure?

Comment: With constant coefficients the answer is affirmative. This is proved, for instance, in Theorem 5.1 (pg.240) of Eilenberg and Steenrod's classic *Foundations of Algebraic Topology*.

Comment: I am aware that for "nice" spaces, such as CW complexes, that Čech cohomology agrees with singular cohomology and hence follows all of the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms (including homotopy invariance). However, I am wondering if homotopy invariance is always satisfied and, if not, then under which circumstances it is.

Answer (score 5):

You do not make explicit which definition of Čech cohomology you are using. I guess it is the "classic" one based on nerves of open coverings. Here are two references giving proofs of the homotopy invariance of Čech cohomology:

1. The timeless classic from 1952

- Eilenberg, Samuel, and Norman Steenrod. Foundations of algebraic
  topology. Vol. 2193. Princeton University Press, 2015.

Have a look at Chapter IX "The Čech homology theory":

> In this chapter the Cech homology and cohomology theories are
> defined and the axioms for such are verified.

The homotopy axiom is stated as Theorem IX 5.1.

2. Another classic from 1967

- Spanier, Edwin H. Algebraic topology. Springer Science & Business Media, 1989.

Have a look at Chapter 6 "General cohomology theory and duality".

In section 4 the Alexander cohomolgy theory is introduced and the homotopoy axiom for Alexander theory is proved in section 5 (Theorem 6). In section 7 Čech cohomology theory is introduced (with coefficients in a presheaf; the constant presheaf gives coefficients in a module $G$). Spanier does not verify the axioms directly from the definition, but proves that Čech cohomology and Alexander cohomology agree for paracompact spaces (see section 8 Corollary 8). In particular, this proves the homotopy invariance of Čech cohomology.

Comment: For those of us without access to these books, can you at least say whether the answer is yes or no? The answer to this question is stated nowhere on the public internet that I could find so it would be nice if there were at least one place (here) that did state it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oops, you are absolutely right. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you! ${}$

Comment: @PaulFrost Apologies - I didn't realise there were different definitions of Čech cohomology. I will edit my question to include this. Could you please be more specific where in the chapter you are referring to?

Comment: @JoelSpringer I made an update.