Does Alexander duality hold without assuming local contractility for compacts on $\mathbb S^2$?
Consider $\mathbb S^2$ and two compact subsets $E, F \subset \mathbb R^2$ such that $F\subset E$. Additionally, assume that $F$ is a deformation retract of $E$.

Question: Is it true that $\mathbb S^2 \setminus F$ is connected is connected when $\mathbb S^2 \setminus E$ is connected?

What I know so far: This is indeed the case if $E$ and $F$ are compact and locally contractible due to the Alexander duality:
$$\tilde H_0(\mathbb S^2 \setminus F) \simeq \tilde H^1(F) \simeq \tilde H^1(E) \simeq \tilde H_0(\mathbb S^2 \setminus E) = 0,$$
where we are making use of reduced homology and cohomology.
Nevertheless, I want to drop the condition that $E$ and $F$ are locally contractible.
Additionally, it would be pleasing as well to find low-tech proof for my question (assuming it is indeed true).

Do you know Chech cohomology? This is the tool one uses to answer (positively) questions such as yours.

I do know a bit. I am not sure, but I believe I can use Cech cohomology instead of the reduced one. Will I have $\check{H}^1(E)=\check{H}^1(F)$ because $E$ and $F$ are homotopy equivalent?

In fact, quoting from the Wikipedia article you linked: "Note that we can drop local contractibility as part of the hypothesis if we use Čech cohomology, which is designed to deal with local pathologies."

@BenSteffan If $E$ and $F$ are homotopy equivalents, then $\check{H}^1(E)=\check{H}^1(F)$?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4523870/is-%C4%8Cech-cohomology-homotopy-invariant
